# How to write scripts in outlook to combines ThisOutlookSession and module

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried to rewrite the code as below
Could you please help me how to code in Case 2: SenderEmailAddress = multi address?
Thanks you very much. May I also use array for the ConditionA. Please see my edit.

```
Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients 
Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient 
Set recips = mail.Recipients 

    'Case 1: If the mail is sent TO multi address (recips), in recips contains 1 email A@x.com'
    Select Case recips
    Case "A@x.com"
        Recipients = Array("A@f.com")
        xStr1 = "<p>A1</p>" 
        xStr2 = "<p>A2</p>"
    
    'Case 2: If the mail is sent TO multi address (recips), in recips contains 3 emails A@x.com B@x.com C@x.com'
    Case "A@x.com", "B@x.com", "C@x.com"
        Recipients = Array("A@f.com", "B@f.com", "C@f.com")
        xStr1 = "<p>B1</p>" 
        xStr2 = "<p>B2</p>"
    
    End Select
```

---

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem) 
Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem 
Set myFwd = Item.Forward 

Dim xStr1 As String
Dim xStr2 As String
Dim Recipient As String

'Case 1: If the mail is sent TO A@x.com'
If obj.SenderEmailAddress = "A@x.com" Then
    Recipient = "A@f.com"
    xStr1 = "<p>A1</p>" 
    xStr2 = "<p>A2</p>"

'Case 2: If the mail is sent TO A@x.com B@x.com C@x.com'
ElseIf obj.SenderEmailAddress = "A@x.com" "B@x.com" "C@x.com" Then
    Recipient = "A@f.com"
    Recipient = "B@f.com"
    Recipient = "C@f.com"
    xStr1 = "<p>B1</p>" 
    xStr2 = "<p>B2</p>"
Else
    MsgBox "None of the conditions was true, abort."
    Exit Sub
End If

myFwd.Recipients.Add Recipient 
myFwd.HTMLBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HTMLBody 

myFwd.Send 
Set myFwd = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: If you have this as condition `"A@x.com", "B@x.com", "C@x.com"` what happens if a email was to `"A@x.com", "B@x.com"`? Because as you have defined it now that means it will only trigger if all 3 are in the recepients but if only 2 are in it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal `If … ElseIf … EndIf` construct or do some research on `Select Case`.

```
Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem) 
    Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set myFwd = Item.Forward 

    Dim xStr1 As String
    Dim xStr2 As String
    Dim Recipients() As Variant

    If ConditionA Then
        Recipients = Array("A@f.com")
        xStr1 = "<p>A1</p>" 
        xStr2 = "<p>A2</p>"
    ElseIf ConditionB Then
        Recipients = Array("A@f.com", "B@f.com", "C@f.com")
        xStr1 = "<p>B1</p>" 
        xStr2 = "<p>B2</p>"
    Else
        MsgBox "None of the conditions was true, abort."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Recipient As Variant
    For Each Recipient In Recipients
        myFwd.Recipients.Add Recipient 
    Next Recipient

    myFwd.HTMLBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HTMLBody 
    myFwd.Send 

    Set myFwd = Nothing 
End Sub
```

---

For checking for multiple recipients you can try something like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim myFwd As Outlook.MailItem
    Set myFwd = Item.Forward

    Dim xStr1 As String
    Dim xStr2 As String
    Dim Recipients() As Variant

    Dim Recips As Outlook.Recipients
    Set Recips = mail.Recipients
    
    ' 2 Cases:
    ' 1. Get email from a1,a2,a3,b1
    ' 2. Get email from a1,a2,a3
    '
    ' a1,a2,a3,b1 it matches a1,b1 -> Forward to b2
    ' a1,a2,a3 it matches a1 -> Forward to b1,b2
    If AreRecipientsInList(Array("a1", "b1"), Recips) Then
        ' Case 1: a1 and b1 are in a1,a2,a3,b1 -> Forward to b2, do not check other criterias
        ' Case 2: a1 in in a1,a2,a3 but b1 is not -> do nothing, check next criteria
        Recipients = Array("b2")
        xStr1 = "<p>A1</p>"
        xStr2 = "<p>A2</p>"
    ElseIf AreRecipientsInList(Array("a1"), Recips) Then
        ' Case 1: a1 is in a1,a2,a3,b1 -> but since case 1 would alerady match above it does not check this criteria here
        ' Case 2: a1 in in a1,a2,a3 -> Forward to b1,b2
        Recipients = Array("b1", "b2")
        xStr1 = "<p>B1</p>"
        xStr2 = "<p>B2</p>"
    Else
        MsgBox "None of the conditions was true, abort."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim Recipient As Variant
    For Each Recipient In Recipients
        myFwd.Recipients.Add Recipient
    Next Recipient

    myFwd.HTMLBody = xStr1 & xStr2 & Item.HTMLBody
    myFwd.Send

    Set myFwd = Nothing
End Sub


Public Function AreRecipientsInList(ByRef MatchRecips() As Variant, ByVal Recips As Outlook.Recipients) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Boolean
    RetVal = True
    
    Dim MatchRecip As Variant
    For Each MatchRecip In MatchRecips
        Dim ThisRecipIsFound As Boolean
        
        Dim Recip As Outlook.Recipient
        For Each Recip In Recips
            If Recip.Address = MatchRecip Then
                ThisRecipIsFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Recip
        
        If Not thiscecipisfound Then
            RetVal = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next MatchRecip
    
    AreRecipientsInList = RetVal
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.
Could you please help me how to code in Case 2: SenderEmailAddress = multi address?

Comment: @TSPham You can solve this by using an array for recipients and loop through that array to add them. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks you very much. May I also use array for the ConditionA. Please see my edit.

Comment: @TSPham That does not work. You need to work with `OR` statements in your `If` statement. Alternatively you can use a `Select Case` block.

Comment: @PEH Thanks you very much. I tried to use Select Case. Please see my edit.

Comment: @TSPham Well that does not work neither because the question that you changed to, is entirely different from your original question and needs an entirely different approach. You primarily asked A and now you are asking B, you got an answer for A. • Is this your final question now or will you change it again?

Comment: Sorry for confusing.
I'm newbie programming, so I haven't figured out what conditions I need and how I'm asking to achieve my goals.
At first I thought with the first question that might solve my problem.
Then I changed the question to another question hoping to find a solution.
I rewrite my purpose in detail.

Comment: I receive a lot of emails every day.
I'm like an intermediary, after receiving an email from company A, I will forward the email to group of people in company B.
For example:
1. Company A sends Emails to me and groups of people
 1a. If this email has group of people a1 (group of company a) then autoforwad for group b1, b2 (group of company B)
 1b. If this email has people group a1,b1, it will autoforwad for group b2
 1c. If this email has a group of people a1,b1,b2, autoforwad will not be performed

Comment: I'm just an office administrator, I want to learn vba programming to support my email work. And I'm not a programmer.
I'd be happy if I'm better at programming, thanks for your guidance. :)

Comment: So just to clarify, if only a part of the group matches, then do nothing. Only forward if the entire group matches?

Comment: And one more question is it just about forwarding the exact email you received or do you change something in that email? Because if it is just about forwarding you don't need any VBA for that you can much easier do that with rules in Outlook.

Comment: if only a part of the group matches, then forward. 
Email To: a1,a2,a3 -> Forward b1,b2 ( matchcase a1)

Comment: if only a part of the group matches, then forward. 
Email To: a1,a2,a3,b1 -> Forward b2 ( matchcase a1,b1)

Comment: if the entire group matches, then do nothing.

Comment: I will add more job requirements, deadlines for each group I forward. I used to use rules in Outlook but...

Comment: See my edit, if it helps

Comment: Thank you. I tried and it show. Variable not defined -> Sub AutoForwardAllSentItems(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Comment: Well declare the variable that is not defined.